# Semigroups containing an appropriate subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

We are looking for a class of non-monoid semigroups $S$ (resp. monoids $M$) satisfying the following conditions:

**(1)** $S$ has a left identity;

**(2)** There exists a subgroup $H$ of $S$ (resp. $M$) such that for every $s\in S$ (resp. $s\in M$), the equation $xs=s$ has the **only solution $x=1_H$** **in $H$**;

**(3)** $H$ contains a **proper** sub-semigroup $K$ such that $\Big(H\setminus K\Big)^{-1}\subseteq K\cup\{1_H\}$ (for a subset $A$ of a group $A^{-1}:=\{ a^{-1}:a\in A\}$).

**Note.** It is easy to see that:

(a) $M=\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual addition), $H=\mathbb{Z}$, and $K=\mathbb{Z}_+$ satisfy all the above conditions (for the monoid case).

(b) Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a monoid and $M:=R(\mathcal{M})$ the sub-monoid of all its right
invertible elements. Put $H:=U(\mathcal{M})$ (the set of all invertible elements of $\mathcal{M}$). Then, $M,H$  satisfy the condition (2), and there is such sub-semigroup $K$ if
$H$ is a torsion-free abelian group (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727584/positive-negative-partition-of-groups and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group). But what classes of monoids $\mathcal{M}$ should be chosen for obtaining the property for $H$?

Do you know such **$S$ (resp. $M$) with the properties** (and any related topic or reference)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for.  You can take a linearly ordered group $H$ with semigroup of positive elements $K$ and a set $X$ of cardinality at least $2$ and take $S=H\times X$ with the multiplication $(h,x)(h',y) = (hh',y)$ and this will meet all your criteria including not being a monoid.  But it doesn't seem to be an interesting example.